# Fitted values in R forecast missing date / time component

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I've been doing a variety of models in R with time series data (in XTS format) and I keep running into the same issue where there's no date / time component to the fitted values / forecasts and thus I can't graph them on the same graph as the original data.

Using the following code, from everything I see online I SHOULD get two line graphs on the same graph.  However, I just get the original graph from the plot command and the second line never appears.

```
library("stats")
library("forecast")
model_a1 <- auto.arima(GED$Mfg.Shipments.Total..USA.)
plot(GED$Mfg.Shipments.Total..USA.)
lines(fitted(model_a1), col = 2)
```

If I plot just the residuals:

```
plot(fitted(model_a1))
```

I get a graph, but instead of having the date / time, it just says "Index" with a range of 0 - 1,2000 on the x-axis.

Any ideas as to what's causing this?  I can't find anything on why an XTS time series would result in residuals with no date / time component.  Also, I tried to post images but apparently there's a silly rule where if you don't post at least 10 times, you can't post images to further explain your problem.....

```
str(GED) 
An ‘xts’ object on 2018-01-01/2115-12-01 containing: 
Data: num [1:1176, 1:472] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ... 
  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2 
        ..$ : NULL
        ..$ : chr [1:472] "SRPM..USA." "WTI" "CU..Argentina." "CU..Australia."  
... Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC 
   xts Attributes: NULL
```

Comment: I think you were lucky to get any answer at all. You are mixing multiple different packages. The XTS data-type is a hybrid that depends on a zoo-type structure (with the data in a _numeric_ matrix) and I don't think there were any guarantees or assurances that `forecast` functions _should_ give you everything wrapped up in a delectable format..

Comment: I'm fairly inexperienced with R (I'm sure you're just SHOCKED to hear that) and I just put together what I found on various sites - most of it coming from stackoverflow.

Comment: There is an Index component to xts-objects. You should post the output of str(GED)

Comment: str(GED)

An ‘xts’ object on 2018-01-01/2115-12-01 containing:

  Data: num [1:1176, 1:472] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2

  ..$ : NULL

  ..$ : chr [1:472] "SRPM..USA." "WTI" "CU..Argentina." "CU..Australia." 
...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

I know the years are off by 100 years due to an import issue from Excel, but that's not a concern right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the dates in your plot, use a numeric sequence as x axis. You can use the dates as labels. Try something like this:

```
y=GED$Mfg.Shipments.Total..USA.
n=length(y)
model_a1 <- auto.arima(y)
plot(x=1:n,y,xaxt="n",xlab="")
axis(1,at=seq(1,n,length.out=20),labels=index(y)[seq(1,n,length.out=20)],
     las=2,cex.axis=.5)
lines(fitted(model_a1), col = 2)
```

The result depending on your data will be something similar:

[image]