# How to show date labels on the X-axis for the forecasted values in R?

Tags: r, plot, prediction, forecasting, axis-labels

We have used the `forecast` function to forecast future values as follows:

```
library("zoo")
library("forecast")
Lines = "20/03/2014,9996792524
21/04/2014,8479115468
21/09/2014,11394750532
16/10/2014,9594869828
18/11/2014,10850291677
08/12/2014,10475635302
22/01/2015,10116010939
26/02/2015,11206949341
20/03/2015,11975140317
09/04/2015,11526960332
29/04/2015,9986194500
16/09/2015,11501088256
13/10/2015,11833183163
10/11/2015,13246940910
16/12/2015,13255698568
27/01/2016,13775653990
23/02/2016,13567323648
22/03/2016,14607415705
11/04/2016,13835444224
04/04/2016,14118970743"
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, sep = ",", header = TRUE, index = 1:1, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
x <- ts(z,f=4)
fit <- ts(rowSums(tsSmooth(StructTS(x))[,-2]))
tsp(fit) <- tsp(x)
plot(x)
lines(fit,col=2)
fit
fcst <- forecast(fit)
plot(fcst)
```

However, the plot `fcst` does not show time/date labels on the x-axis and instead just shows generic numbers 1,2,3...

[image]

To understand forecasted values, we need monthly date labels on the x-axis. How can we do this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the generic date-on-axis problem. The `read.zoo` is properly importing the values as `POSIXct` values. Most of the time series functions preserve the proper date values. Or at the very least find a `ts()` specific duplicate.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you. I have found that some people on here are very quick to mark something as "duplicate" without taking the time to comprehend the problem. I have irregularly spaced date stamps in my data and I need the forecasted values to be marked against future dates.

Comment: Why you are doing `ts(z,f=4)` if your data is irregular? You want to transform into quarterly? If it is the case is better to look at 
`xts::to.period`

Comment: @Robert I thought about that and I recently just fit it over the original data instead: `> fit <- ts(z)
> tsp(fit) <- tsp(z)
> plot(z)
> lines(fit,col=2)
> fit`   But the time labels on the x-axis are still a problem

Comment: It is not so difficult when you have the correct time series. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30991982/2824732. But in your case you cannot apply functions like `StructTS` that are designed to regular data.